# Formatting Control-M auto edit variables

Tags: control-m

Is it possible to format "%%TIME" auto edit variable to "HH:MM:SS".
Without any formatting it plainly output as "HHMMSS".

Any help is appreciated....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Only way I know is to do something like:

```
%%HOURS            %%SUBSTR %%TIME 1 2
%%MINUTES          %%SUBSTR %%TIME 3 2
%%SECONDS          %%SUBSTR %%TIME 5 2
%%FORMATTED_TIME   %%HOURS.:%%MINUTES.:%%SECONDS
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below option.

you can declare auto edit variable "%%TEST" value in SET tab as below.

`date +'%H:%M:%S'`